Great expectations - value counts equal exactly 3



ID.
Column B




ID1
value1


ID2
value2


ID1
value3


ID2
value4


ID1
value5


ID2
value6



I have the table above. I want to check using Great Expectations if each unique value in column ID occurs exactly 3 times. How can I achieve that?
I couldn't find any expectation matching this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
